# Where do I download a precompiled version of QtWebKit for Qt 5.8 and MSVC2015

Tags: qt

I found a link to a place to download a precompiled version of QtWebKit for Qt 5.8/MSVC2015 here on Stackoverflow a few months ago but can't seem to dig it up anymore. (Asking me to use QWebEngine won't help -- it's not working and it appears to be impossible to get it work).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since Qt no longer ships binaries of `QtWebKit` since its deprecation, probably what you had found before is the link to binaries of `QtWebKit` [revival project](https://github.com/annulen/webkit) - currently there are available binaries of "technology preview 5" pre-release version: https://github.com/annulen/webkit/releases/tag/qtwebkit-tp5.